# gulp-task output in console is not printing expected result

Tags: javascript, gulp, wiredep

I have the following gulp task which inserts `.css` and `.js` files in the html file:

```
gulp.task('inject', function () {
    log('Injecting the JS and CSS files into index.html');

    var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
    var options = config.getWiredepDefaultOptions();

    return gulp.src(config.index)
        .pipe(wiredep(options))
        .pipe($.inject(gulp.src(config.customFiles), {ignorePath: options.ignorePath}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.client));
});
```

and my `gulp.config.js`:

```
module.exports = function () {
    var client = './public';

    var config = {
        allJS: [
            '*.js',
            'public/js/*.js',
            'public/js/**/*.js'
        ],
        client: client,
        index: client + '/index.html',

        customFiles: [
            './public/css/*.css',
            './public/js/*.js',
            './public/js/**/*.js'
        ],

        bower: {
            json: require('./bower.json'),
            directory: './public/lib',
            ignorePath: '/public/'
        },

    };

    config.getWiredepDefaultOptions = function () {
        var options = {
            bowerJson: config.bower.json,
            directory: config.bower.directory,
            ignorePath: config.bower.ignorePath
        };

        return options;
    };

    return config;
};
```

This works as expected, but when I run the task I get this:

[image]

It always says `gulp-inject 3 files into index.html`, even though no new files was added.

Is there something wrong with my gulp file?

Comment: Are you using gulp-inject? Are you saying there are no files under './public/css/*.css', './public/js/*.js', './public/js/**/*.js'

Comment: @MichaelWarner There are 3 files there, but should I get the message when those files are already injected?

Comment: From what I see you should always get the message unless you tell the injector to be in quiet mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you are using gulp-inject this is what I found.

If you look at the code in gulp-inject you can see it just spits out the file count unless it gets opt.quiet set. I didn't see a option in the docs for this setting but if you look at the tests it shows an example it being used.

Enabling quiet mode [link](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject/blob/master/src/inject/inject_test.js) line 505

```
inject(sources, {quiet: true});
```

Source where it generates the log statement. [link](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject/blob/master/src/inject/index.js) line 109

```
function getNewContent(target, collection, opt) {
  var logger = opt.quiet ? noop : function (filesCount) {
    if (filesCount) {
      log(cyan(filesCount) + ' files into ' + magenta(target.relative) + '.');
    } else {
      log('Nothing to inject into ' + magenta(target.relative) + '.');
    }
  };
```